# ANTLR error(99) grammar has no rules

Tags: antlr

I previously posted about my first attempt at using ANTLR when I was having issues with left recursion.

Now that I have resolved those issues, I am getting the following error when I try to use org.antlr.v4.Tool to generate the code:

```
error(99): C:test.g4::: grammar 'test' has no rules
```

What are the possible reasons for this error?  Using ANTLRWorks I can certainly see rules in the Parse Tree so why can't it see them?  Is it because it cannot find a suitable START rule?

Comment: Well, if you resolved your earlier problem, could you either post the answer/solution there, or remove the question?

Comment: Can you post the grammar, and post exactly how you're trying to generate the parser/lexer classes using the `Tool`?

Comment: You may have a syntax error in the file which is causing ANTLR to stop parsing. Can you post your grammar up through (and including) the first rule?

Answer (score 10):

I think Antlr expects the first rule name to be in small case. I was getting the same error with my grammar

```
grammar ee;
Condition : LogicalExpression ;
LogicalExpression : BooleanLiteral ; 
BooleanLiteral :  True ;
True : 'true' ;
```

By changing the first production rule in the grammar to lower case it solved the issue i.e. the below grammar worked for me.

```
grammar ee;
condition : LogicalExpression ;
LogicalExpression : BooleanLiteral ; 
BooleanLiteral :  True ;
True : 'true' ;
```

Note: It is my personal interpretation, I couldn't find this reasoning in the online documentation.

Edit: The production rules should begin with lower case letters as specified in the latest docs [1]

[1] https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexicon.md#identifiers

Comment: I met the same issue. I think the names of grammar rules (aka the non-terminal rules) must be in all lower-case.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you've found the solution for this, but I had the same problem and fixed it by changing my start symbol to 'prog'. So for example, the first two lines of your .g4 file would be:

```
    grammar test;
    prog : <...> ;
```

Where <...> will be your first derivation.

Answer (score 1):

I just got that error as well (antlworks 2.1).
switching from 
`RULE : THIS | THAT ;` to `rule : this | that ;` for parser rules (i.e. from uppercase to lowercase) solved the problem!

**EDIT**
The above correction holds only for `RULE` , what follows after the `:` can be any combination of lexer/parser rules

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is just what the error message suggests.  And the most likely reason for that is that you have not saved your grammar to the file--or if you're using ANTLRWorks2--ANTLRWorks hasn't saved your work to the file.  I have no idea why ANTLRWorks doesn't save reliably.

Comment: With your remark *"I have no idea why ANTLRWorks doesn't save reliably"*, you're assuming it's ANTLWorks that is malfunctioning and not the OP. I bet it's the other way around.

Comment: I said ANTLRWorks doesn't save reliably because it does it to me, which is how I knew a likely answer to the OP's question.

Comment: Your reasoning is incorrect.  It _is_ **an** answer, and had I seen it when I first encountered error(99) it would have been _the_ answer.  Given that the file save problem is easily reproducible in ANTLRWorks2 it is even--as I said--a likely answer.  BTW, only I have mentioned ANTLRWorks2.  Are we even talking about the same software?  Clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error but could not fix it.
I downloaded ***antlrworks-1.4.jar*** and it's working perfectly.

Download >> [antlrworks-1.4.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/antlrworks/antlrworks-1.4.jar.zip)

Answer (score 0):

Changing the first rule to start with a lower case character worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and this means that your grammar has no Syntactic rules. So in order to avoid this error, you need to write at least one Syntactic rule.